# Abelization of a group is trivial iff ...

Tags: group-theory

Does there exist a theorem like:
The abelianization of a group $G$ is trivial if and only if $\dots$ .

I'm searching for a "nice" criterion to decide whenever or not the abelianization of a group is trivial (or not).

All I know is, that there are infinite many groups with the property, that there abelianization is trivial, but the group is it not. This follows directly by the fact that $(G\times H)^*\cong G^*\times H^*$, where $G$ and $H$ are groups and $G^*$ denote the abelianization of $G$. So I just need only one group $G$ with the property, that $G^*=0$, but this is common knowledge.

Comment: One formal criterion is, if and only if the commutator subgroup $[G, G]$ is $G$ itself, i.e. if and only if $G$ is a [perfect group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_group).

Comment: You are just paraphrazing the definition.

Comment: I did say "formal criterion".

Comment: I can't understand what is not complete or what is wrong with Zhen's comment: a group has trivial abelianization if either it itself is abelian (and this isomorphic to its abelianization) or else it is a perfect group, i.e. equal to its commutator subgrou. What else? It seems like you're looking for conditions for a group being perfect...? For example, simple non-abelian groups are perfect .

Comment: For groups defined by a finite presentation, the abelianization is trivial if and only if the Smith Normal Form of the matrix of the presentation has $n$ 1s along the main diagonal, where $n$ is the number of generators. But maybe that is also just paraphrasing the definition?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one such result:

> Let $G$ be a group. Then $G$ has trivial abelianisation if and only if for any abelian group $H$, there are no nontrivial group homomorphisms $G \to H$.

For any group homomorphism $\varphi : G \to H$ where $H$ is abelian, $[G, G] \leq \ker\varphi$. If $G$ has trivial abelianisation, then $G = [G, G]$, so $\varphi$ must be trivial.

For the converse, consider the natural projection $\varphi : G \to G/[G, G]$. As $G/[G, G]$ is abelian, $\ker\varphi = G$, but $\ker\varphi = [G, G]$ by definition, so $G = [G, G]$ and hence $G$ has trivial abelianisation.

---

Note, the above is related to the universal property of the abelianisation. Let $\varphi : G \to G/[G, G]$ be the projection. Then for any abelian group $H$ and homomorphism $f : G \to H$, there is a unique homomorphism $F : G/[G, G] \to H$ such that $f = F\circ\varphi$. That is, any group homomorphism between $G$ and an abelian group factors through the abelianisation of $G$.